# How to start odoo server automatically when system is ON

Tags: python-2.7, webserver, odoo-8, odoo, odoo-10

Haii everyone

How to start Odoo server automatically when system is ON.

Normally i searched in google i had found a link " http://www.serpentcs.com/serpentcs-odoo-auto-startup-script-322 "

i follow the each and every step and i started the odoo-server

ps -ax | grep python

5202 ?        Sl     0:01 python /home/tejaswini/Odoo_workspace/workspace_8/odoo8/openerp-server --config /etc/odoo-server.conf --logfile /var/log/odoo-server.log

it is showing the server path also

but when i run 0.0.0.0:8069/localhost:8069 in browser it is running 
shows This site can’t be reached

please any one help me 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start a service automatically when the system turns on, you need to put that service into init script. Try below command

```
sudo update-rc.d <service_name> defaults
```

In your case,

```
sudo update-rc.d odoo-server defaults
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks for your response. when i start the server its running. Using  sudo /etc/init.d/odoo-server start. I restart the server and check the server runs automatically but its not happens. when i use sudo /etc/init.d/odoo-server start then it will run. u have any idea about this

Comment: Thank u sir --> sudo update-rc.d odoo-server defaults this command is working...... :) . If u don't mind can u explain this command what is rc.d

Comment: Check this site http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/update-rc.d.8.html
Please accept and upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the final step we need to install a script which will be used to start-up and shut down the server automatically and also run the application as the correct user. There is a script you can use in `/opt/odoo/debian/init` but this will need a few small modifications to work with the system installed the way I have described above. here is the [link](http://www.theopensourcerer.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/odoo-server)

Similar to the configuration file, you need to either copy it or paste the contents of this script to a file in `/etc/init.d/` and call it odoo-server. Once it is in the right place you will need to make it executable and owned by root:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/odoo-server
sudo chown root: /etc/init.d/odoo-server
```

In the configuration file thereâ€™s an entry for the serverâ€™s log file. We need to create that directory first so that the server has somewhere to log to and also we must make it writeable by the openerp user:

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/odoo
sudo chown odoo:root /var/log/odoo
```

[reference](http://www.theopensourcerer.com/)

Comment: Sir server is running problem is solved. But here my intention is to start the server automatically when system ON. But when i restart the system and check the running servers (ps ax | grep python) it is showing empty. its not happens it is not automatically runs. when i use sudo /etc/init.d/odoo-server start then it is running. u understand my problem ...?? sir